# How to import/call between files in your own module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I am trying to understand how to write your own modules, by trying to create a simple one, but I don't seem to understand how to use the __init__ file, and this whole import stuff works.

So right now I have a package called "helloWorld", and the structure looks like this:

```
helloWorld
    __init__.py
    helloWorldFile.py
    helloBonjourFile.py
```

and these are the contents for each file:

__init__.py:

```
from helloWorldFile import helloWorldClass
```

helloWorldFile.py:

```
import helloBonjourFile

class helloWorldClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.keyword = 'Hello Beautiful World'

    def hello(self):
        print self.keyword
        helloBonjourFile.run()
```

helloBounjourFile.py:

```
def run():
    print 'Bonjour Mon Ami!'
```

So the idea is, i want to run whatever that is in "helloBonjourFile" from "helloWorldFile", so I try running this in a Python shell:

```
import helloWorld
reload(helloWorld)
helloWorld.helloWorldClass().hello()
```

It prints out the "Hello Beautiful World" part fine, but after that i keep getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

I am pretty sure I am going about this incorrectly, how do i correctly run both the contents of "helloWorld" and "helloBonjour"? I'd like to keep the file that actually runs these things to a minimum...

I also would like to figure out a way to pass arguments into "helloBonjour" if possible...

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, for anyone else that may be having similar issues, this was caused by editing one file and trying to run from the custom module in the same environment, and was solved by running a reload() command for every file. but you have to do it in the order of files being imported, in my case i had to reload in the following order:

```
reload(helloBounjourFile)
reload(helloWorldFile)
reload(helloWorld)
```

and that should do the trick.... if it doesnt try it a few times more for it to refresh (at least that worked for me)...